# Which libraries does Sherlock exclude?

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

Action Bar Sherlock, while being a neat library, as you might know, has two to three pretty invasive elements:

1. It forces you to inherit your Fragments and Activities from SherlockFragments and SherlockActivities. This is a sparse resource which you can't use for another handy library that might require you to do the same. Luckily the compat library isn't one of them (actually it is, but Sherlock builds on it).
2. It uses an Android library project. Since the tooling for these can't quite be called very stable yet, you might run into problems sooner. In fact, I have run into Eclipse bugs.
3. It's yet another library that makes Proguard's job harder and adds to your apk's size. Apk sizes are still a huge limitation for some users, among which Google TV users.

As such, what other possible (future) libraries, including 3rd party ones, would I be excluding if I choose to use Action Bar Sherlock? Any other limitations I'm missing?

Comment: You are not forced to extend from the base activities or fragments. They are provided for convenience.

Comment: Just for clarity: If you want to actually use the functionality, and interact with the action bar, you have to inherit from the Sherlock-flavored ones. From your homepage: "When creating an activity to use the action bar on all versions of Android, you must declare your activity to extend any of the activity classes that start with 'Sherlock' (e.g., SherlockActivity, SherlockFragmentActivity)." Correct? Using another library with the same requirements together with it will always lead you to do custom work to mix both classes, with possible non-trivial consequences, if not only in maintenance.

Comment: That's not true at all. The only required part is using a Sherlock theme. You can do everything else from the exposed API without the base activity or base fragments.

Answer (score 1):

> As such, what other possible (future) libraries, including 3rd party
>   ones, would I be excluding if I choose to use Action Bar Sherlock? Any
>   other limitations I'm missing?

Frankly, I don't know of any. Most libraries which are making the use of a custom implementation of `Activity`(like ActionBarSherlock is doing as well) will most likely extend `SherlockActivity`(since almost everybody uses ABS) or if not then you could just modify it yourself. So no, as far as I can tell there won't be any limitations.

Comment: I'll hold on for a while to see some more results, and then accept your answer, if it is indeed 'none'.

Answer (score 1):

1. As @Jake Wharton himself pointed out this is just not true.  Using the existing code and examples, it is a simple and fairly quick implementation for creating custom ABS activities and fragments.
2. I use library projects extensively, including having library project references that go multiple levels deep.  I've run into a few issues, but nothing that was a deal breaker. Eclipse gets confused sometimes on rebuilds, but usually cleaning all the projects gets everything sorted out. Library projects are getting more stable all the time.
3. This is actually two points, but with a similar theme -- for *any* library, not just ABS, you have to tradeoff the value you get from including the library's features against the cost of doing so.  I feel the value of the interface right now is worth the extra effort and apk size.  This is a value decision that needs to be made on a per app basis.

@Ahmad is correct, ABS poses obvious no limitations on 3rd party libraries. It might take some coding to integrate, but they should work together.  Furthermore, ABS use will fade naturally in the future.  It is a compatibility library, so as the device distribution shifts more and more to Android 3+ devices, the need to support action bar UIs on 2.X devices will be less of an issue.

Comment: About 2.: The FAQ (http://actionbarsherlock.com/faq.html) seems to state otherwise under "Why is ActionBarSherlock a library project whereas the original compatibility library is only a .jar?". Or are you suggesting that you can drop all resources, drawables and themes from ABS, use it purely as a jar and then roll your own?

Comment: About 3.: The additional apk size is about 300 - 500kB, I presume?

Comment: Pre-dex its about 350-400KB. Dexing will reduce that a bit. If you really, REALLY are concerned about space you can delete the unused theme resources but that will only give you about an extra 80KB pre-dex.

Comment: about 2.  You are correct, I was in error there.  I have corrected the post.  As I said, I use the library function, and am quite happy with it.